# Looking for a Java EE 6 application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm looking for a Java EE 6 application using JPA to build JUnit test cases and a regression tool.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This application tutorial uses JPA, CDI, Bean Validation, etc. Maybe it can work for you:

http://www.andygibson.net/blog/news/demo-application-using-jsf-jpa-cdi-with-jetty/